# Lots of unwanted packets installed in ubuntu 12.04 with apt-get due to typing mistake. How to revert?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, apt

In my virtual `ubuntu 12.04`, I was installing `ruby2.3` but by mistake, I have put space in between `ruby` and `2.3`.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby 2.3
```

It has installed more than 9 GB packages including multiple kernels.

What to do? How can I revert back? What if I execute below command to remove all unwanted packages?

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove 2.3
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

What is the side effect of this command? There are lots of important data in my virtual System. So can I restart my system?

As @Alex requested, Here I am attaching output of `sudo dpkg -l |grep ruby`.

```
ii  liblocale-ruby1.8                                   2.0.5-2                                             pure ruby locale library
ii  libmemcache-client-ruby                             1.7.8-2                                             Ruby client library for memcached
ii  libmemcache-client-ruby1.8                          1.7.8-2                                             Ruby client library for memcached (Ruby 1.8)
ii  libruby                                             4.8                                                 Transitional package for libruby1.8
ii  libruby1.8                                          1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1.6                                Libraries necessary to run Ruby 1.8
ii  libtzinfo-ruby                                      0.3.19-1                                            Ruby library for transformations between time zones
ii  libtzinfo-ruby1.8                                   0.3.19-1                                            Ruby library for transformations between time zones (Ruby 1.8)
ii  rake                                                0.9.2.2-2                                           ruby make-like utility
ii  ruby                                                4.8                                                 Transitional package for ruby1.8
ii  ruby-actionmailer-2.3                               2.3.14-2                                            Framework for generation of customized email messages
ii  ruby-actionpack-2.3                                 2.3.14-2ubuntu0.12.04.1                             Controller and View framework used by Rails
ii  ruby-activerecord-2.3                               2.3.14-1ubuntu0.12.04.1                             ORD database interface for ruby
ii  ruby-activeresource-2.3                             2.3.14-1                                            Connects objects and REST web services
ii  ruby-activesupport-2.3                              2.3.14-2ubuntu0.12.04.2                             Support and utility classes used by the Rails 2.3 framework
ii  ruby-blankslate                                     2.1.2.4-2                                           Ruby library providing a class with no predefined methods
ii  ruby-builder                                        3.0.0-2                                             Ruby library to facilitate programatic generation of XML markup
ii  ruby-i18n                                           0.6.0-1                                             I18n and localization solution for Ruby
ii  ruby-mecab                                          0.98-5build1                                        mecab binding for Ruby language
ii  ruby-rack                                           1.3.5-1                                             Modular Ruby webserver interface
ii  ruby-rails-2.3                                      2.3.14-2                                            MVC ruby based framework geared for web application development
ii  ruby-rchardet                                       1.3-2                                               Character encoding auto-detection for Ruby
ii  ruby-rvm                                            1.6.9-0ubuntu2.1                                    easily install, manage and work with multiple ruby environments
ii  ruby-text-format                                    1.0.0-3                                             Ruby library for text formatting
ii  ruby-tmail                                          1.2.7.1-1build1                                     Mail class library for Ruby
ii  ruby1.8                                             1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1.6                                Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby 1.8
ii  ruby1.8-dev                                         1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1.6                                Header files for compiling extension modules for the Ruby 1.8
ii  rubygems                                            1.8.15-1ubuntu0.1                                   package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of 'sudo dpkg -l |grep ruby' ?

Comment: I have modified my question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `sudo apt-get -s install ruby 2.3` (notice `-s` switch, i.e. simulation, no harm done) in my Debian. It matched lots of packets with *2.3* string. I'm fine but you for sure have many packets you don't want.

I also run `sudo apt-get -s --purge remove 2.3`. It tried to remove every packet with *2.3* string, already installed or not. Don't do that because it may remove a packet you need, unless you are absolutely sure you had had no such packet before the mishap.

**Safe thing to do is to analyze `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/dpkg.log`** (at least this is what I have in Debian). You will learn what exactly happened and what was installed in vain. With that knowledge you may pick unwanted packets and remove them.

To make this systematic and reduce the risk of error I suggest copying the `history.log` and editing the copy. Delete all extra information, leave packet names and build a command line with `apt-get purge`. Double check with original log and run the resulting command (e.g. make that file a `bash` script and execute). This way you will avoid error-prone typing and won't miss any unwanted packet.

**I haven't tested this. Since the OS is virtual, you may want to backup it before applying my solution, just in case.** I'm not sure if you can do a backup of the running system though. Maybe your setup allows to "freeze" it, clone/snapshot/backup, then resume.